# Is a terminal and USB Device or a USB Host

Tags: device, host, stm32, usb-otg

If I use Tera Term, to connect to a USB OTG port on a STM32 MCU, is Tera Term a USB Device or a USB Host.

The question arises as I presumably could configure the STM32 OTG port to be a USB Host CDC or a USB Device CDC.

It's possible that it doesn't matter what I configure the STM32 USB OTG port as, but it's possible that there may be a specific standard that defines what should be done.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use Tera Term, to connect to a USB OTG port on a STM32 MCU, is Tera Term a USB Device or a USB Host.

Neither.

**Your computer** is a USB host. The software running on your computer doesn't affect its role.

Comment: I see that now. I was confused in looking at the application, when it's the hardware configuration that defines the role to be USB Device or USB Host. Now I also extrapolate that and see that a USB Host cannot connect to a USB Host, thus what you have indicated is clearly the case. Thanks.